# Why are some windows not enumerable?

Tags: winapi

I was doing some tests on Window relationships, and found out that there are some windows that aren't accessible via the `EnumWindows()` and `EnumChildWindows()` functions.

Some I found by going up to the root of the relationship tree to the root node (nullptr) via `GetParent()` and another I found by peeking into the messages that were being sent around.  Is there no way to find these handles?  If so, how?  If not, is it done this way for security purposes, or is something broken?

## Edit

I've added a repo of the code (including the VS solution I did) [here](https://github.com/Ma-XX-oN/WindowTree), in case anyone is interested in taking a look.  When I run it unmodified, it gives me a single `not enumable` HWND with the class name `Message`.  Why that isn't included in the message windows, I don't know.  Changing the line `allocate_nodes(false)` to `allocate_nodes(true)` in the `main()` function, will force looking for other HWNDs that weren't found using the published interfaces.  I'm not sure if these are real or phantoms, though it does capture the `not enumable` HWND.

Some sample output:

```
handle #!window_status!got expected!visible!tree!class name!window title
         1!       special!correct!0!"00000000"!!
         2!       special!correct!1!" 00010010"!#32769!
         3!     top level!correct!0!"  00010290"!ComboLBox!
         4!     top level!correct!0!"  000102FE"!ComboLBox!
         5!     top level!correct!0!"  000404A0"!ComboLBox!
         6!     top level!correct!0!"  000404A4"!ComboLBox!
         7!     top level!correct!0!"  00040822"!ComboLBox!
         8!     top level!correct!0!"  00071DF8"!ComboLBox!
         9!     top level!correct!0!"  000A0FF6"!ComboLBox!
        10!     top level!correct!0!"  001A1CD0"!ComboLBox!
        11!     top level!correct!0!"  001C1626"!ComboLBox!
        12!     top level!correct!0!"  001E1C30"!ComboLBox!
        13!     top level!correct!0!"  001F17FC"!ComboLBox!
        14!     top level!correct!0!"  002B19E8"!ComboLBox!
        15!     top level!correct!0!"  003517D2"!ComboLBox!
        16!     top level!correct!0!"  00351906"!ComboLBox!
        17!     top level!correct!0!"  00351AE4"!ComboLBox!
        18!     top level!correct!0!"  003714D2"!ComboLBox!
        19!     top level!correct!0!"  003916E2"!ComboLBox!
        20!     top level!correct!0!"  00421248"!ComboLBox!
        21!     top level!correct!0!"  005B0472"!ComboLBox!
        22!     top level!correct!0!"  006517CA"!ComboLBox!
        23!     top level!correct!0!"  00680E16"!ComboLBox!
        24!     top level!correct!0!"  006F11D0"!ComboLBox!
        25!     top level!correct!0!"  00751B08"!ComboLBox!
        26!     top level!correct!0!"  007A165E"!ComboLBox!
        27!     top level!correct!0!"  00840C0E"!ComboLBox!
        28!     top level!correct!0!"  009816AC"!ComboLBox!
        29!     top level!correct!0!"  009E0EE2"!ComboLBox!
        30!     top level!correct!0!"  00A01AAC"!ComboLBox!
        31!     top level!correct!0!"  00B1134A"!ComboLBox!
        32!     top level!correct!0!"  00BA10F8"!ComboLBox!
        33!     top level!correct!0!"  00C00994"!ComboLBox!
        34!     top level!correct!0!"  00E014C0"!ComboLBox!
        35!     top level!correct!0!"  00EA0452"!ComboLBox!
        36!     top level!correct!0!"  00F911E2"!ComboLBox!
        37!     top level!correct!0!"  014913EC"!ComboLBox!
        38!     top level!correct!0!"  015804D0"!ComboLBox!
        39!     top level!correct!0!"  018E0FF0"!ComboLBox!
        40!     top level!correct!0!"  01D60FA4"!ComboLBox!
        41!     top level!correct!0!"  021E087C"!ComboLBox!
        42!  not enumable!correct!0!" 00010012"!Message!
        43!       message!correct!0!"  0015184E"!ScriptedMessageWindow!
        44!       message!correct!0!"  005C0C54"!AccessibleNotificationsWindow!
        45!       message!correct!0!"  00A6043A"!ScriptedMessageWindow!
        46!       message!correct!0!"  00E80DEE"!ScriptedMessageWindow!
        47!       message!correct!0!" 00010014"!#32774!
        48!     top level!correct!0!" 00010048"!Dwm!DWM Notification Window
        49!       message!correct!0!" 00010086"!#43!MCI command handling window
        50!       message!correct!0!" 0001008A"!OleMainThreadWndClass!OleMainThreadWndName
        51!     top level!correct!0!" 0001008C"!DDEMLMom!
        52!     top level!correct!0!" 00010090"!DDEMLEvent!
        53!       message!correct!0!" 00010094"!OleMainThreadWndClass!OleMainThreadWndName
        54!       message!correct!0!" 00010098"!WorkerW!AppResolver_NotifyWnd
        55!       message!correct!0!" 000100A8"!OleMainThreadWndClass!OleMainThreadWndName
        56!       message!correct!0!" 000100B0"!CicMarshalWndClass!CicMarshalWnd
        57!       message!correct!0!" 000100B2"!UserAdapterWindowClass!
        58!       message!correct!0!" 000100BC"!OleMainThreadWndClass!OleMainThreadWndName
        59!       message!correct!0!" 000100C0"!CicMarshalWndClass!CicMarshalWnd
        60!     top level!correct!0!" 000100CC"!PushNotificationsPowerManagement!Windows Push Notifications Platform
        61!     top level!correct!0!"  000100CE"!IME!Default IME
        62!       message!correct!0!" 000100D6"!UserAdapterWindowClass!
        63!       message!correct!0!" 000100DC"!UserAdapterWindowClass!
        64!     top level!correct!0!" 000100E2"!GDI+ Hook Window Class!G
        65!     top level!correct!0!"  000100E4"!IME!Default IME
        66!     top level!correct!0!" 000100E8"!#32770!The Event Manager Dashboard
        67!     top level!correct!0!"  000100EA"!IME!Default IME
        68!     top level!correct!0!"   00010102"!MSCTFIME UI!MSCTFIME UI
        69! not top level!correct!0!"  000100F0"!Button!OK
        70! not top level!correct!0!"  000100F2"!Static!Activity Information
        71! not top level!correct!0!"  000100F4"!Button!Cancel
        72! not top level!correct!0!"  000100F6"!ListBox!
```

The default field separator is `!`, but can be changed at the top of the source file.  I wonder what all of these hidden ComboBoxes are for that are off of the Desktop?

Comment: The standard example is a [message-only window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/window-features#message-only-windows).  Use the Spy++ utility to find out more about it.

Comment: That's what I was looking for @HansPassant.  However, is the source code for Spy++ available?

Comment: also you need have [*disableWindowFiltering*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sbscs/application-manifests) in manifest - *TRUE disables window filtering so you can enumerate immersive windows from the desktop.*

Comment: It used to be, part of the SDK samples.  Takes a museum trip though, back to around 1998.  Just use it.

Comment: Lol.  Well, the tip on the message-only windows found 99.9% of the windows.  There was just one (that I'm aware of) that wasn't enumerated.  Not sure about how to generate a manifest file though @RbMm.

Comment: @HansPassant, add your answer in your comment as an an answer and I'll accept it.  Thanks.

Comment: I just can't see what you saw, be sure to share what you discovered in your own post and mark it as the answer.

Comment: @HansPassant, actually, I did a brute force method and found that there were many more Windows than I found before.  So, I'm going to have to check out how to disable window filtering.

Comment: @RbMm, tried to add a manifest.  Not sure if it worked.  It didn't actually allow me to enumerate over all of the windows though. 
 Can you please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53330015/how-to-generate-a-manifest-file-for-vs-2017-for-a-c-project-and-be-sure-its-wo?  Thanks.