# How to generate a manifest file for VS 2017 for a c++ project and be sure its working?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

I've been looking around trying to figure out how to generate a manifest file for a c++ application for VS2017.  I've seen some stuff for [VS2010](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/629067/How-to-add-a-manifest-file-in-my-project), and the only thing I've seen for VS2017 is [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/manifest-generation-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2017) on the MS site.  However, actually generating the file wasn't clear.  So what I did was:

1. Go to project properties
2. Go to `Configuration Properties > Manifest Tool > Embed Manifest` and 
   set it to `No`.
3. Apply and build.

I now have an external file named `filename.exe.manifest` next to my `filename.exe`.  I then added the following bold and italic info to the manifest which I got from [disableWindowFiltering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sbscs/application-manifests) on the MS site (unfortunately, not a direct link as there are no anchors on the page):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0"

  xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">

  <asmv3:application>
    <asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2011/WindowsSettings">
      <disableWindowFiltering>true</disableWindowFiltering>
    </asmv3:windowsSettings>
  </asmv3:application>

  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"></requestedExecutionLevel>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

Once done, I executed the application.  It didn't seem to change the results.  I still couldn't enumerate all of the windows using `EnumWindows()` and `EnumChildWindows()`.  The process is also running under admin rights too.

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: _"disableWindowFiltering was added in Windows 8"_ -- you propably have to add a [`<Compatibility>` element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SbsCs/application-manifests#elements) to declare that your application is compatible with Windows 8.

Comment: @zett42 - `disableWindowFiltering` work in manifest and without `compatibility` (tested)

Comment: *It didn't seem to change the results. I still couldn't enumerate all of the windows* - you try say that no difference at all with/without this attribute in manifest or difference exist, but *still couldn't enumerate all of the windows* ? difference must exist. for test simply enumerate all visible top level windows. with this attribute say must be some windows with class name `Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow`, which not listed without this attribute. manifest can be [next](https://pastebin.com/SBAnnvd7)

Comment: Is it possible you originally started the application before the .manifest file was in the application directory? In such cases it seems Windows caches the application as having no manifest somehow, and it doesn't matter if you add a manifest file to the directory afterwards: it has no effect whatsoever. In that case: rebuild application, then make sure the .manifest is in the .exe's directory, then start it. From then on changes do have effect (at least I could reproduce this on 2 different machines)